# How to get list of all stackoverflow tags filtered by a mask?

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions, stack-exchange

Currently, when a question is being created/modified, I can see up to 6 tags in a popup when typing a keyword.

I'm not sure what is proper tag name I'm searching for and whether it exists at all.

Is it possible to get a full list of tags filtered by a mask somewhere?

Comment: Built-in tag queries are fixed.  This information is available in the [data dump](http://blog.stackexchange.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/).  You can feed it into a dbase and query it whichever way you want.  Also accessible from [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/), SQL required.

Comment: It's true, in some tags you really need to wear a mask because there is so much garbage. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the tags button near the top of the page and type some letters you think may be in the tag in the search box.

Comment: I must notice it :-) . Thank you!